# Setting up Omnis Studio to extract data from a .DF1 file

Tags: mysql, sqlite, odbc, omnis-studio-10

My clients have been using Master Repair 8000 for the past decade to keep track of their invoicing and all of their data has been saved to a .DF1 file. They have requested to transfer all of the data from the Master Repair 8000 program to a MySQL database.

I've been surfing around for solutions to this problem and I found the following text from an accompanying forum post

[You can use an evaluation copy of Omnis Studio to copy the data from the Omnis data file into a MySQL database. Using the SQL Browser utility, you create an OMNISSQL session that connects to the data file (.DF1) and a MYSQL session that connects to your MySQL database. Open both sessions. You can then use drag and drop to copy whole tables directly over to MySQL. If you want continued access to MySQL after the trial period expires, it will require a standard developer license I believe.](https://www.omnis.net/community/forums/forum/discussion/database-converter-df1-df2-and-df3/?no_frame=1)

So I attempted to follow this guide and have done the following.

1. I've downloaded Omnis Studio Community edition
2. I've downloaded the SQLite binary from the official SQLite website
3. I've downloaded the ODBC Manager application.
4. From the ODBC Manager application I created a new System DSN and confirmed it was able to connect to the .DF1 database/file. I confirmed the DSN is able to successfully connect to the file/databse.

Now that I've set everything up I need to make a OMNISSQL connection to the .DF1 database/file so that I can then transfer the data over to a MySQL database.

The setup page for this connection looks like the following:[OMNIS studio OMNISSQL connection wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tha3C.png)

Now for the hostname, it's prompting me to put the DSN name and I leave the remaining fields blank since I'm not really sure what else I'm supposed to put in those fields. When I try this I get the following error message:

[The SQL Browser was unable to log on :
[iODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocEnv() failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAX2W.png)

I'm not sure what this error message means and I've searched online to no avail. Does anyone know how I can set up a OMNISSQL connection to a .DF1 database in Omnis Studio in order to transfer .DF1 data into a MySQL database?

Comment: If you have managed to [setup a user with access to all the tables and created a System DSN](https://www.omnis.net/developers/resources/onlinedocs/index.jsp?detail=ExtendingOmnis/12odbcdriver.html), then you could use the [MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) to import the data.